# How to UPSERT multiple rows with individual values in one statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I've created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
a   INT UNIQUE, 
b   varchar(100) NOT NULL,
c   INT, 
d   INT DEFAULT 0,  
PRIMARY KEY (a,b));
```

On a single row this SQL statement works great (the SQL is generated in code):

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a, b, c, d)
VALUES($params.1, '${params.2}', $params.3, params.4) 
ON CONFLICT (a,b) DO 
UPDATE SET d=params.4
```

Is it possible to upsert multiple rows at once? For each update the value of `params.4` is different.

```
var sqlStr = 'INSERT INTO t1 (a, b, c, d) VALUES '
for(let i =0 i < params.length; i++){
   sqlStr += `(${params[i].1}, '${params[i].2}', ${params[i].3}, ${params[i].4}),`
   
}
sqlStr = sqlStr.substring(0, sqlStr .length - 2) +')';
sqlStr += 'ON CONFLICT (a,b) DO UPDATE SET **d=???**' <-- this is the problem
```

`params[i].4` has different value for each row and the `ON CONFLICT` statement appears only once (not per row) and `SET` doesn't support a `WHERE`.

Example, if my table has the following rows:

```
 a | b | c | d 
---+---+---+---
 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
 2 | 2 | 2 | 2
```

And my new input is `[(1,'1',1,11),(2,'2',2,22),(3,'3',3,3)]`.
There are two conflicts - `(1,1)` and `(2,2)`. The result should be:

```
 a | b | c | d 
---+---+---+---
 1 | 1 | 1 | 11
 2 | 2 | 2 | 22
 3 | 3 | 3 | 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPSERT (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE`) keeps track of excluded rows in the special table named **`EXCLUDED`** automatically. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.9)

> Note that the special `excluded` table is used to reference values originally proposed for insertion

So it's really very simple:

```sql
INSERT INTO t1 (a, b, c, d)
VALUES (...) 
ON     CONFLICT (a,b) DO UPDATE
SET    d = EXCLUDED.d;          -- that's all !!!
```

Besides being much simpler and faster, there is a subtle corner-case difference from your proposed solution. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> Note that the effects of all per-row `BEFORE INSERT` triggers are
> reflected in `excluded` values, since those effects may have contributed
> to the row being excluded from insertion.

Plus, column `DEFAULT` values are already applied in the `EXCLUDED` row, where no input was given. (Like `DEFAULT 0` for your column `d`.)

Both are typically what you want.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo ;)

I've updated my question with an example to fine tune the problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: @KukulaMula: You seem to have missed the essential part. Use `EXCLUDED`!

Answer (score -3):

Writing the solution for future users dealing with the same issue

Step 1: Create a temporary table (clone of t1)

```
CREATE TABLE t2(                 
  a   INT UNIQUE, 
  b   varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  c   INT,                                  
  d   INT DEFAULT 0,  
  PRIMARY KEY (a,b));
```

OR

```
create table t2 as (select * from t1) with no data;
```

Step 2: Insert the new input to t2

```
INSERT INTO t2 (a, b, c, d) 
values (1,'1',1,1),(2,'2',2,2),(3,'3',3,3)`
```

Step 3: UPSERT to t1 in case of conflict select d from t2

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a, b, c, d)
VALUES (1,'1',1,1),(2,'2',2,2),(3,'3',3,3)
ON CONFLICT(a,b) DO UPDATE
SET d=(SELECT d FROM t2 WHERE t2.a=t1.a);
```

Step 4: delete t2

```
DROP TABLE t2;
```

Comment: No. Just no. Use the special `EXCLUDED` table instead. So much simpler and cheaper. And this is incorrect on top. `WHERE t2.a=t1.a` would have to be `WHERE t2.a=t1.a AND t2.b=t1.b`.