# Postgres ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT triggering errors in the error log

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds, upsert

I have a sql statement with `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT` in it to allow upserting.  This seems to be working well except that my error logs have a bunch of errors related to this query.

I am confused by the error logging because we expect to run into this constraint and then just do the update - is there something broken here or is this just chatty logging?

RDS Postgres, version 12.7.

```
2021-12-18 16:00:32 UTC:172.31.1.154(33952):{username}@{database}:[28367]:ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "segments_sequence_number_event_id"
2021-12-18 16:00:32 UTC:172.31.1.154(33952):{username}@{database}:[28367]:DETAIL: Key (sequence_number, event_id)=(2, d5c70xxxx63478) already exists.
2021-12-18 16:00:32 UTC:172.31.1.154(33952):{username}@{database}:[28367]:STATEMENT: INSERT INTO segments (id,created_at,updated_at,event_id,sequence_number,start_time,end_time,bitrate,width,height) VALUES ('8e6d5xxxxbdae3','2021-12-18T16:00:32.596Z','2021-12-18T16:00:32.596Z','d5c70xxxx63478',2,1639843218000,1639843221000,2097152,1920,1080) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT sequence_number_event_id_unique DO UPDATE SET updated_at='2021-12-18T16:00:32.596Z',start_time=1639843218000,end_time=1639843221000,bitrate=2097152,width=1920,height=1080 RETURNING id,sequence_number,url,start_time,end_time,duration,bitrate,width,height,size,event_id,created_at,updated_at
```

Comment: Please post the offending SQL statement along with the DDL statments of the relevant tables/indexes etc.

Comment: @SebDieBln: The offending statement is hidden in the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ON CONFLICT` clause uses `ON CONSTRAINT sequence_number_event_id_unique`

But the unique violation is raised by different constraint: `unique constraint "segments_sequence_number_event_id"`

To catch any and all conflicts, you can use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.
`ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` can only catch a single "conflict target" (a single constraint, index, or index expressions).

Related:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

Aside: You don't have to pass values twice. You can just reuse values from excluded rows with:

```sql
...
SET (updated_at,start_time,end_time,bitrate,width,height)
  = (EXCLUDED.updated_at,EXCLUDED.start_time,EXCLUDED.end_time,EXCLUDED.bitrate,EXCLUDED.width,EXCLUDED.height)
...
```

See:

- [How to UPSERT multiple rows with individual values in one statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775370/how-to-upsert-multiple-rows-with-individual-values-in-one-statement/68775428#68775428)

Corner-case difference: Values from the `EXCLUDED` row include changes from possible triggers `ON INSERT` (which is typically desirable).

Comment: @pherris: The names seem to indicate duplication with confused names. Maybe you can drop a duplicate constraint?

Comment: I agree - these look like the same constraint accidentally applied twice with slightly different names.

Comment: Consider the added aside.